# Can a backwards infinite regress account for its own existence?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, ontology, theology, infinity

Suppose we have a domain of discourse D with an infinite collection of elements, and suppose that it is the case that the existence of each element x is dependent upon another element y (or collection of elements Y). (Technical note: Let's say "dependent upon" is a non-symmetric, non-reflexive relation. That is, x cannot depend on x, and if x depends on y, y does not depend on x).

My question is not whether such a regress is possible, but rather if the objects within D can account for their own existence. Note I'm *not* asking why the *set* D exists, as a set is an abstract mathematical object. Rather, I am asking the question:

**Question**: Why is there at least one element in D at all?

It seems that this question cannot be answered without reference to an object outside of D, for whatever element or group of elements within D whose existence we try to explain will make reference to other elements in D, which pre-supposes that there is at least one element in D, which is the question we're trying to ask in the first place, and is hence this circular reasoning.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you clarify what it means for an element to account for its own existence? For example in {1, 2, 3, banana}, do any of these elements account for their own existence or depend for their existence on other elements? I'm not sure what you mean. In the integers {..., -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...} if we said that n+1 "depends on n for its existence," it would be the case that every element has something to depend on for its existence, yet there is no first element.

Comment: Not very clear... also taking into account Tags: theology? philosophy of mathematics? Having said that, the example you are using is about set theory: in this case we have either the explicit axiom asserting the existence of one set (the empty one), or the theory relies on the fact that on "usual" first-order logic "exists x (x=x)" is a valid and thus it rules out empty domains.

Comment: Re:"Why is there at least one element in D at all?" In a nutshell, a theory "speaks of" some piece of reality (either physical or abstract): we call it its "domain of discourse". If there is none, pace radical skeptics, what is the "meaning" and use of the theory that speaks of it?

Comment: @user4894 I clarified in my post that "depend upon" should be a non-symmetric, non-reflexive relation. In everyday language, x cannot account for its own existence, and if y accounts for x's existence, then x cannot account for y's existence.

Comment: @user4894 Yes, but you get a sort of paradox here. While each element is accounted for by another element, you still get no answer to why there are elements of that sort at all. You always have to pre-suppose a prior element, which really is no answer to the question.

Comment: To elaborate on what I think user4894 was trying to get at, without any further explanation of what "depends upon" means conceptually, there is nothing wrong with presupposing a prior element. As it currently stands, you seem to just be using "depends upon" as a funny name for some relation analogous to >.

Comment: @Sandejo Thanks. But I want an answer to the following question: "Why are there any of these elements at all, to begin with?" I don't think one can answer that question unless they 1. Make reference to something outside of the set, or 2. make reference to something inside of the set, which is circular reasoning.